# Open a task pane when an appointment is accepted or created

Tags: outlook, office-addins

So the gist of it is that I am trying to open an outlook task pane whenever the user creates an appointment or updates it.

It should be simple but I havent found a solution yet.

I have tried the AutoShowTaskpanes, however, When trying to install them on Outlook for the web, it returns a "Document" is invalid on XML

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically open a Task Pane in the Outlook clients.  The capability only exists for Word, Excel and PowerPoint. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document.